# How do get the test metrics using sonarqube 5.3 web services?

Tags: sonarqube

This command seems not working in sonarqube 5.3:

ex with  URL="http://localhost:9000/sonar" :

This is OK:

> curl -ks "$URL/api/resources?resource=MyProject&metrics=comment_lines,comment_lines_density,public_documented_api_density,public_undocumented_api" |  jq -r '.[].msr[] | "(.key) : (.val)"'

This is not OK:
curl -ks "$URL/api/resources?resource=${projectKey}&metrics=coverage,line_coverage,branch_coverage,tests,test_execution_time,test_errors,test_failures,test_success_density" |  jq -r '.[].msr[] | "(.key) : (.val)"'

How do get the test metrics using sonarqube 5.3 web services ?

Note: I'am using the [cxx](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki) community plugin v0.94

Dominique

Comment: Works for me: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube&metrics=comment_lines,comment_lines_density,public_documented_api_density,public_undocumented_api

Comment: sorry..the command is following: curl -ks "$URL/api/resources?resource=MyProject&metrics=coverage,line_coverage,branch_coverage,tests,test_execution_time,test_errors,test_failures,test_success_density" |  jq -r '.[].msr[] | "\(.key) : \(.val)"'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise: the coverage (using gcovr 3.2) had not been launched correctly and the data provided by the web services were (normally) empty.